# Can testing set be used as validation set

Tags: python, machine-learning

Can testing_set be used as validation_set ?

Does validation_set have any affect on model learning or used for checking validation accuracy only for each epoch ?

I am using keras library for the building model .

```
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
                      batch_size=batch_size,
                      epochs=epochs,
                      verbose=2,
                      validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use validation set to figure out how much you overfit and to decide when to stop learning. So to get a more or less "independent" quality measure of your model you need another set of data, which is test set.

Please refer to following [discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set) for more information.

If you're using Keras you can pass `validation_split` parameter to the model, so that Keras splits train set data for you.

Answer (score 0):

For a test set to be a *true* test set, the labels should never be supplied to the model. If you use the test set also as the validation set, then although your model isn't necessarily training on the validation set, it will have *seen* the labels for this set during training

So, in short, you really need three **distinct** sets of data for training, validation, and test.

If you need additional resources, [here](https://youtu.be/Zi-0rlM4RDs) is a video that breaks these sets down into their distinct purposes, and [here](https://youtu.be/dzoh8cfnvnI) is another one for working with validation sets in Keras.